# Anytime I submit changes in EECMS I get DB result printout

Tags: error, file-manager, bug

Anytime I make a change within the eecms admin, I get DB table readouts instead of the ol' green light.

I deleted my DB in the event that it became corrupted during the install. Downloaded a fresh copy of eecms from EllisLab, installed, same issue. Only thing I can think of is that I'm using Media Temple hosting for the first time. Not sure if there's special install procedures for them or not.

Specifically, every time I choose File Manager I get: {"rows":[],"pagination":""}

Everything is technically "working," but I shouldn't be getting these DB readouts.

[image: DB text readout I keep getting]

[image: Folder structure (someone asked for this)]

Comment: Have you re-uploaded you themes folder? Can you post a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Please take a moment to provide more detail to your question.

Comment: @DerekHogue Yes, I re uploaded each individual folder to see if that was the culprit. I finally removed the install, deleted the DB, downloaded a fresh copy of eecms, reinstalled, same issue. 

Only thing I can think of is that I'm using Media Temple hosting for the first time. Not sure if they have special configuration for eecms? I know some servers come pretty locked down out of the box.